# PHP - Can't find some folders in System32

Tags: php, directory, system32

During two hours, I've tried to find an issue for my problem.
I have a script which sorts folders of **System32** :

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($_SERVER["SystemRoot"] ."\System32");
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isDir())
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "<br />";
}
```

But when I check result, I see that some folders are missing.

[image: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/46385214pb.jpg]

Someone has an idea to solve it ?
Thanks a lot.

**Edit** : When I create a new folder, it's not find too.

**Edit'** : I work on a Windows Server 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5).

Comment: check read permission of dns for webserver

Comment: Everybody can see it : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/501745pb2.jpg

Comment: Windows has been using UAC (User Account Control) for some years now. A program that tries to create files in system-wide locations will be tricked into thinking he succeeded but actual file will be somewhere else. Not sure if you took that into account.

Comment: There is a way to find what is the real path ?

Comment: First of all, gather some basic information. What user created the *dns* folder? What user does your PHP process run as? Is UAC enabled or disabled?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a php script on this server that update a log file : it gets ip address of client website. It's executed by a program every 15 minuts : it works fine and there is no problem when I update internal logs file (Inetpub > wwwroot). So, dns folder is created for IIS users. I have disabled UAC after your answer and reboot the server, but I always cannot find dns folder by php. :(

Comment: When UAC is enabled, files created in restricted locations end up in a place like "C:\Users\johnsmith\AppData\Local\VirtualStore". However, I suspect your PHP process runs under a system user called `IUSR_<machine-name-here>` that probably doesn't have a home directory. (Now I have to ask: why save a such log in system folders?)